# Naming acids, oxidation numbers and charges

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, nomenclature

I have been studying chemistry for a short time and studied the nomenclature of inorganic compounds. I got to naming acids, and got really confused with several things, including the definition of oxidation number. Let me explain myself:

I started studying using the book Chemical Principles: The Quest for Insight and in the naming acids section, it is said that an acid is formed by an oxoanion and positive hydrogen. To write the formula of an acid, use the prefixes to find the oxoanion (which I don't really know hot to do, because take "nitrate". How do I know the number of oxygens needed? How do I know if it is $\ce{NO-}$, $\ce {NO_2-}$ or $\ce {NO_3-}$?) and then add as much hydrogens as negative charge there is.

Then I came across another equivalent method that uses the oxidation numbers of the elements: it says you have to memorize a set of oxidation numbers of each element, like $\ce{Cl}$ has $-1, 1, 3, 5, 7$, etc. Then a table is shown associating each oxidation number to a prefix and suffix, like +1 corresponds to hypo-, -ous for $\ce{Cl}$, etc. Then combine this element with the corresponding charge with $\ce{O^2-}$ and add water ($\ce{H2O}$) to it. Let me give an example to show the two methods:

Take sulfuric acid.

**Method I)** The corresponding oxoanion is Sulfate ion, $\ce{SO4^2-}$ which has charge 2-, and so we add 2 $\ce{H+}$ to it, thus getting $\ce{H2SO4}$.

**Method II)** The corresponding charge for sulfur according to the table for the suffix -ic is +6. Thus we have the ions $\ce{O^2-}$ and $\ce{S^6+}$. Exchanging the oxidation numbers gives the compound $\ce{S2O6}$, which simplifies to $\ce{SO3}$. Adding the water molecule (i. e. adding 1 $\ce H$ and 2 $\ce O$) gives $\ce{H2SO4}$.

So I have a few questions regarding this: why do both methods work and which one is "more correct"? I would say **II** is the most correct since acids are said to be molecular compounds, but I'm not sure at all. Also, in a general acid $$\ce{H_a X_b O_c}$$
which are the oxidation states of each of the elements? I thought the oxidation number of $\ce X$ was negative, the oxidation number of $\ce H$ was +1 and the oxidation number of $\ O$ was (exceptionally) 0. It turns out that's wrong, right? Or is the oxidation number not the same as the charge?
Thanks in advance and sorry for the long question

Answer (score 0):

The method used for naming the acids was adopted in the beginning of the 19th century. It goes like this. We first chose all the known acids with $b = 1$ in the formula $H_aX_bO_c$.

If there is only one such acid, its name is made of the name of X plus the suffix $-ic$. Ex.: $H_3BO_3$ is the $boric$ acid. $H_2CO_3$ is the $carbonic$ acid.

If there are two acids, the most oxidized is named by the previous rule. In the less oxidized acid, the suffix is changed into $-ous$. Ex. $HNO_2$ and $HNO_3$ are known. The first is nitrous acid, the second is nitric acid.

If there are four such acids, the two acids in the middle are named after the previous rule. The name of the most oxidized is obtained by adding the prefix $per-$. The name of the least oxidized is made by adding the prefix $hypo-$.
Ex. Four acids are known with $X$ = $Cl$ : $HClO$ is $hypochlorous$ acid ; $HClO_2$ is  $chlorous$ acid ; $HClO_3$ is $chloric$ acid ; $HClO_4$ is $perchloric$ acid.

There are no known cases where more than 4 different acids are known. If there are only three known acids, one guesses(!) a fourth formula. Ex. With $X = Br$, the following acids are known :  $HBrO, HBrO_3$ and $HBrO_4$. Their names are $hypobromous$ acid, $bromic$ acid, and $perbromic$ acid.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer. My question wasn't quite about the naming of acids themselves, which I think I understand, but the equivalence of your method with the one I talked about, using H2O added to the molecule. Thanks!